# Does Delphi XE produce faster code than Delphi 2007?

Tags: delphi, optimization, delphi-xe

I've been using mostly Delphi 2007 for projects that don't need Unicode.

Lately I've been wondering about Delphi XE because

- everybody is praising it;
- build-in SVN support

I was wondering though, have there been any enhancements in the compiler that make Delphi XE to produce faster code than Delphi 2007, I'm talking about things like:

- better elimination of dead code (delphi 2007 is decent, but does not eliminate 100% of dead code)
- loop unrolling (ala C's O3 optimization level)
- auto inlining of short routines
- less overhead in multithreaded code.

**EDIT**

On this page: http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/whats-new

It lists: `Improved compiler performance` 
So what exactly is improved?

Comment: One of the reasons an executable rebuilt in XE should be faster is simply that it's using Unicode APIs since the native internal APIs are Unicode (on NT-based Windows and later). D2007 calls Ansi APIs and every call with string parameters might cause potential translation to and from Unicode internally.

Comment: It's very rare for Win32 string api calls to be a bottleneck.

Comment: I've been doing a bit of number crunching in Delphi lately, writing `gold` editions as benchmark for CUDA code. Not much unicode in that I'm afraid :-). You raise a good point though I always figured ansistring to be faster because it uses less memory, but forgot about the translation issues.

Comment: @David Sure, the difference in performance will depend on how much you actually call them. Some apps might do a lot, others not. I just thought it's worth mentioning.

Comment: @all, many thanks for a series of very informative answers

Comment: Loop unrolling is not a always a good idea nowadays. See http://agner.org/optimize in his optimizing_assembly.pdf file, page 101: "Core2 and Nehalem processors perform much better on loops that are no bigger than 64 bytes of code. Loop unrolling will decrease performance on the Core2  if it makes the loop bigger than 64 bytes. (See manual 3: "The microarchitecture of 
Intel, AMD and VIA CPUs".)".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Two points, for my two cents:

**1. For our Open Source ORM framework**

When running [our unit tests](http://blog.synopse.info/category/Open-Source-Projects/SQLite3-Framework) with Delphi 7, Delphi 2007 and Delphi 2010 compilers, I found out some speed improvement between Delphi 7 and Delphi 2007, but not noticeable between Delphi 2007 and 2010. Delphi 2010 generated code was found out to be even a bit slower. I don't have a Delphi XE compiler at hand, but I guess it's somewhat the same as Delphi 2010 - mainly bug fixing about generics, AFAIR.

I spent a lot of time in the asm view (Alt-F2) when I write low-level pascal code, and use a profiler. So I usually notice difference between Delphi compiler versions.

IMHO the main improvement was indeed the `inline` keyword for methods and functions/procedures, available in Delphi 2007 and not in Delphi 7. Another improvement was a more aggressive register re-use.

Floating-point generated code is still slow and sometimes awfull (the FWAIT is still produced, even if not necessary any more, and inlining floating-point code could be even [worse than with no inlining](http://delphitools.info/2011/02/08/the-limitations-of-delphis-inline/)!

What is interesting about our framework, and all those tests is that it does process a lot of data, using its own low-level units, coded in very tuned pascal for best performance. And the unit tests provided (more than 5,400,000 individual tests) work on real data (numerical conversion or UTF-8 text processing), with a lot of diverse processes, including low-level conversions, text parsing, object allocations, multi-threading and Client/Server orientation. So here, the code generation by the compiler does make a difference.

The code is mainly inside our framework. We use our own RawUTF8 string type, and not the generic string. Therefore, the bottleneck is not the VCL nor the Windows API, but only pure Delphi compiled code. In fact, we avoid most API calls, even for UTF-8 encoding or numerical conversions.

Of course, I tried this benchmark with PUREPASCAL conditional set, i.e. not running the optimized part in asm, but rely on only "pure pascal" code.

**2. For SynLZ compression unit**

Another good experiment about speed was writing and profiling our [SynLZ compression unit](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2010/06/26/Pure-pascal-LZO-and-SynLZ-compression-units). With this optimized implementation of the LZ compression algorithm, compression is 20 times faster than zip, decompression 3 times faster. In fact, it competes with LZO for compression ratio and decompression speed, but is much faster than LZO for compression: SynLZ is able to compress the data at the same rate than it decompresses it. Such a symmetrical implementation is very rare in the compression world.

It involves only integer arithmetic and bit logic, filling and lookup in hash tables, and memory copy.

We wrote some very tuned pascal code, then compiled it with Delphi 7 and Delphi 2009.

The Delphi 2009 generated code was faster than Delphi 7, in a noticeable way. Generated code was indeed better, with better register reuse.

With hand-tuned assembler profiling, we achieved even better performance. For instance, a 6 KB XML file is compressed at 14 MB/s using zip, 185 MB/s using LZO, 184 MB/s using the Delphi 2009 pascal version of SynLZ, and 256 MB/s with our final tuned asm version of SynLZ.

**Conclusion:**

For the generation of code involving integer process, text parsing or memory , I think Delphi XE is faster than Delphi 7, but should be more or less at the same level than Delphi 2007. Inlining was the main new feature, which could speed up a lot the code.

But for real-world application, speed increase won't be noticeable. About 10 or 20% in some specific cases, not more. Algorithms is always the key to better performance. Delphi 7 was already a nice compiler.

For floating-point arithmetic, the Delphi compiler is nowadays deprecated. I hope that SSE code in 64 bit compiler will change the results here.

To answer directly your question, in Delphi 2010 or XE, there is no auto-inlining nor auto-loop-unrolling, AFAIK. And overhead in multi-threaded code is not part of the compiler, but on the library (FastMM4, reference counting and such). So I don't think Delphi XE produce faster code than Delphi 2007.

Comment: I'd be interested to find out what difference better floating point code gen on x64 makes.

Comment: Is SSE IEEE compliant nowadays then?

Comment: Accepted answer becayse of the profiling background tough one to call though many good answers in this thread.

Comment: @Marco SEE is still 64 bit, therefore the next compiler will probably lack of extended type support.

Comment: @David About SSE performance, you can guess it will be better for computing aggressive calculation. Current [Delphi compiler is outperformed by latest Javascript engines](http://delphimax.wordpress.com/2011/03/29/delphi-beaten-by-javascript) using on the fly compilaton into SSE: you'll have to code SSE by hand for acceptable results.

Comment: Bouchez: x87 FPU is now allowed again by Microsoft (FPC initially didn't allow it on win64, but it changed).  But my point was more that the errorhandling and rounding etc of SSE is not entirely IEEE compliant, so you can't simply recompile scientific code.   SSE was meant to do image and codec computation where saturation avoids exact(scientific) handling of exceptions and rounding.

Comment: @Marco You're 100% right. So you asked a question you already knew the answer? ;) Did you have any benchmark of floating-point code with FPC compared to Delphi? As far as is written [in this comment](http://delphitools.info/2011/03/24/kudos-to-the-firefox-4-tracemonkey-team/comment-page-1/#comment-1528), FPC 2.5.1 generated exe is already faster than Delphi (similar to TraceMonkey, at least), because it handles SSE.

Comment: @Marco: MS made decisions about its compilers, AFAIK x87 code is strictly forbidded only in 64 bit drivers, applications are still free to use x87 code if they want so. SSE is not a superset of x87, some applications may still need the FPU, and even if the compiler does not use it, you can still use them with an assembler. For the matter VC++ does not longer offer an inline assembler, but again that's a MS decision, nothing forbids it in other products (but respecting the stricter 64 ABI).

Comment: @ldsandon: For XP/64 at first FPU was not documented as being allowed, though it did save the regs during contextswitch. Search for XP 64-bit specific stuff and you'll easily find the reference. The rest of your message is mostly my point. Most applications that didn't use SSE but FPU on x86, the same is still the case on 64-bit, not much changed. Just due to the mandatory availability of SSE2 (+ in ABI), more compilers support it. Some Delphi devels have blocked about the first 64-bit Delphi not having internal assembler too last year. I don't know the current situation.

Comment: @Marco AFAIK there will be an assembler in the 64 bit compiler, but not as inlined asm blocks inside pascal blocks, only as plain asm function or procedure. See what David I said: "*There will be internal 64-bit assemblers although we will not be able to mix pascal and assembler code in one method. There will not be an extended type anymore :( If that bothers you (it surely bothers me), send a letter to your local Delphi representative.*" http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2011/03/delphi-down-under.html

Answer (score 10):

My informal testing of the Delphi XE compiler shows that the code generation is noticeably more correct in many cases involving the use of Generics, and that certain compiler internal failures (bugs) that had dogged the compiler in the Delphi 2009, 2010 era, are now fixed.  In many cases, Delphi 2010 code using generics, linked into packages, when rebuilt repeatedly in the IDE, would result in corrupt DCP file output, or mysterious compiler internal errors, during compile and link.

I would have written in the release notes, if it was me, "we fixed the bugs". **(I retract the "Best Ever" phrase, because it seems people think I meant it as advertisement for my then-employer, I formerly worked for Embarcadero).** I suppose that all of that has been smoothed over into the word "performance", where performance is understood as "correctness", and "doing its job reliably, and without glitches".

As for speed, I have not noticed any statistically significant difference in profiling code from Delphi 2009, 2010, or XE, as far as its performance-at-runtime speed, nor the compiler's performance, in terms of "it builds projects faster".

Since you asked about Delphi 2007, you should be aware that there is a huge type change (String=AnsiString, to String=UnicodeString). For the same code, some things will be slower, and some things will be faster, and it's 100% impossible to say what will happen if you recompile your 2007 code in 2010, without knowing lots about your code.  If you relied heavily on WideString before, and you can now use UnicodeString instead, your code will get much faster since UnicodeString performance is much better than WideString performance.  Some delphi programs spend a lot of time in your code quietly (and nearly invisibly) converting your ansi data up to unicode data, internally in win32 , such as when you use a Memo common control. On the other hand, some things that used to use byte-size strings, will now be using word-size strings, so memory usage will increase in some places, and some operations may get slower.  The most likely net result, for properly ported code (you have to make some changes to most applications to get them to build in XE, if you wrote them for 2007) is, if anything, a tiny net decrease in "raw performance".

However, Delphi XE builds projects, and more importantly rebuilds and rebuilds, over and over in the IDE, without incident, and never crashes on me. Delphi 2007 crashed on me all the time.  Delphi 2007 also has hundreds of annoying compiler bugs that would drive me crazy. Compiled-code-speed is not even the main reason to upgrade, reliability is.

Often in large projects I have been using, Delphi 2007, 2009, and 2010  would  crash on the second or third rebuild of some complex set of packages. In 2009 and 2010, packages that made heavy use of generics were especially likely to crash the IDE. XE is stable, even when I use it with heavy generics code, and that is a kind of "performance" improvement that the release notes might be talking about. I call it "bug fixes".Let's call a spade a spade.

**(Deleted last paragraph, because people thought it was an advertisement)**

Comment: Question looks for improvements of XE over D2007. Improved code generation for generics does not really matter here. You only mention D2009-XE in your answer...

Comment: I am trying to explain what the text that the user asks about means.

Comment: @Warren, many thanks, I enjoyed reading your answer very informative with respect to answering the question `why is everybody so happy with Delphi XE` I'm definitly going to give it a go.

Comment: "I would have written in the release notes the most solid, reliable, well tested compiler release ever": just to tell customers of previous version "hey, we've been joking till now"?

Comment: Agree with ldsandon, written as advertisement. Anyway, its too late to buy XE.

Comment: I work for Embarcadero, but I'm not on the RAD team. And if anything, I'm criticizing whoever wrote those release notes.  They didn't want to admit that hey, delphi has bugs.   But hey, suit yourself.  I write my own point of view on StackOverflow, not my employers, and I'm a geek, not a marketer. My final verdict is, if anything, Delphi XE is slower than 2007, but it don't matter none, 'cuz speed is less important than correctness.

Comment: You should clearly state about your affiliation before expressing opinions which can be viewed as biased by stringent readers.

Comment: I will state such affiliations IN my post, when in future, I venture any opinion, positive or negative, on the merits of a product that is for sale by my employer. I get no extra money if you buy it or don't buy, and I'm NOT on the RAD team, I work on other products.  I am also a Delphi user, and I would be PRO DELPHI if I worked at Embarcadero or not.  I would state my opinion MORE STRONGLY if I was not employed by Embarcadero, because then, I wouldn't have to be so polite to "stringent" people.

Comment: Downvoted: a company employee advertising his company products - not matter what his job within the company is, is a kind of conflict of interests. Guess SO should also offer a kind of "flag" for such kinds of posts. Moreovers I'm seeing an increasing "buy XE" activity as the product is reaching its "end of life" status due to a new release approaching, I'd like to know if it is spontaneuos, or instead a marketing-driven effort.

Comment: Ldsandon; Do you agree my edits have removed the advertising-sounding bits?

Comment: Well, hope you don't work for Emb marketing. "We fixed the bugs". Good. You mean you sold me buggy releases till then, right? Thank you, I didn't give you fake money in exchange. I know any program has bugs, but advertising a new releases as "eventually we fixed those bugs we sold you till now" is, let me say, a bit silly. I appreciate Emb people writing here about technical solution, less those telling to but the actual releases, which, of course, is always the "best". Even D2005 was said to be better than previous releases...

Answer (score 5):

I don't see any evidence of any significant improvements on code generation. I'm not aware that there has been anything very significant in terms of code generation improvements since Delphi 5. In fact I've never found my code running faster following an upgrade and that's stretching back to Delphi 2.

Comment: Thanks David, judging from the projects you work on you'd probably have noticed sooner than most.

Comment: The new versions of Delphi are much better though even if the code gen is largely unchanged.

Comment: I only stuck to Delphi 2007, because I use ZEOS database components in some projects and the last stable version of ZEOS does not grok unicode. The alpha version 7 does, but I don't want to use an alpha version in production code.

Comment: I am pretty surprised that ZEOS doesn't have a production version in June 2011, that supports even the 2009 delphi that was released in 2008. That's like 3 years of out-of-date. Maybe time to drop ZEOS?

Comment: Can't agree with this answer. You can feel huge improvements in string manipulations (faster routines like PosEx, IntToStr, etc.), memory management (because of FastMM) when comparing Delphi XE to Delphi 7.

Comment: @Linas That's a good point. As it happens, most people in the know used FastMM with D7 anyway (and D6, D5 etc.) As it happens, I personally don't use heap allocation in the critical regions of my code so FastMM makes little difference (well, beyond actually working with LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE!)

Comment: @Linas This is not the point here: the question was about generated code, not about the library.

Comment: @A.Bouchez I look the comment from @Linas to refer to the final sentence in the answer, in which case it's a reasonable point.

Comment: @Linas: the comparison asked is between D2007 and XE, not D7.

Answer (score 3):

The Delphi compiler is very obsolete today, and is being rewritten. Improvements up to XE looks to be marginal, and the compiler is not really able to take advantage of latest processor capabilities and instruction sets (it is mostly stuck in the 80386 era, but for some RTL code which uses hand written assembler to take advantage of more modern capabilities). XE compiler may be more reliable the previous versions (since D7 quality became very variable), but overall performance improvements would need a total overhaul of the compiler to bring it to the XXI century.
It's been undertaken, but it is not known if the next release will have only a newer 64 bit compiler, and still the old 32 bit one, or if the 32 bit compiler too has a new codebase also.

Comment: Due to the architecture of the Intel/AMD processor, the speed improvement does not come from using opcodes newer than 386 for most common pascal code, involving text, data and integers. Only for floating-point computation and big data handling (like image processing), the new instruction sets like SSE does make a difference. There will be SSE process in the new 64 bit compiler: here will be some real change.

Comment: Even the RTL code in hand written asm is still in the 80386 area: it does not use SSE or anything else, only tuned x86 and x87 asm, with optimized aligned memory access. No sign of MMX/SSE here. ;) But the current 32 bit compiler does good work already: like dead code elimination, clever register use and peephole optimization.

Comment: @A.Bouchez, just curious, what is peephole optimization?

Comment: The downvoter could have explained why he did it, as long as he is able to explain and he's not simply in the category of "Delphi worshipper" trying to send curse on everybody pointing out real issues in his god product. Embarcadero itself has decided to rewrite the compiler, they would have not if it wasn't obsolete.

Comment: A compiler may become obsolete in several ways. Of course a code base you can't easily update to 64 bit IMHO means it could not be easily updated to support newer processor, instructions, and new optimizations also. Rewriting from scratch is always a lengthy, costly and risky task, and usually you throw code away when it became really obsolete. BC++ compiler too lost a lot of ground in the past years to VC++, and GCC (not to mention Intel).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to embaracadero

http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/whats-new

A short way down the page in the

> "Language, Compiler and Library
>   Enhancements"

they make mention of compiler improvements. Not much here but what they don't say is your answer too. That is if they had anything major they'd likely brag about it.